# asp.net Web Api and multiple database

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, asp.net-web-api, multiple-databases

I'm trying to create an API with asp net which uses multiple db.
Basically, for example, I have an action to get all the employees (ex. api/employee) and I'd like to have "api/first_city/employee" which takes the data from the db associate to first_city and "api/second_city/employee" which takes the data from the second db. 
What is the best architecture? I can't find anything that can help me. Any suggestion?
is it possible with asp net web api?
Thanks

Comment: There isn't best architecture for this. Simply consider that faster you can configure your API better your code is so for me the best way is just to correctly develop this part. So in your web.config, declare your two connectionStrings. In your webApi controllers, use constants for connectionString key respectively defined and use a common DAL which just switch to database according to connectionstring key. For this last point, I consider database are identical ;-).

Comment: another way would be to create a general controller with, for ex., the action getEmployee and for each route "api/first_city/employee" create a controller that extend the general one and call getEmployee passing the right connectionString.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to create sevral EntityFramework models for your site
Open your project>>Add New Item >>Data>>ADO.NET Entity Data Model. So, each model will represent different database, then you can start coding using these models.

[image]